# camel - move to folder after processing

Tags: apache-camel

I am working a code which polls a SFTP folder and process them one by one then move them to a success folder once it is done. we run this camel instance more that 1. To process the file by one instance, we have a DB check like once a camel instance takes the file it creates a marker record and any other instances come to pick the file it will check this marker record and skip the process. so we have created a custom exception like Markerdocument available in a processor which will handle that. This marker exception will be handled at globally and we mark them handled "true" so file will not be moved /ERROR folder. Now the problem is, since we are handling this the route process thinks that it is successfully processed and moving the folder to /success which we don't want, this will be handled by the actual record processing camel instance. How do we achieve that?

```
onException(MarkerDocumentExistsException.class)
        .process("routeExceptionProcessor")
        .log("Marker document available so continue next message processing... ")
        .handled(true)
        .stop();    
        onException(Exception.class)
        .process("routeExceptionProcessor")
        .log("Nothing to do here, move the file to error folder... ")
        .redeliveryDelay(2000)
        .stop();
    from(getSftpOptions())
        .routeId("sftp-Route")
        .throttle(Integer.parseInt(appProp.throttleCount))
        .timePeriodMillis(1000*60)
        .onCompletion()
        .onCompleteOnly()
            .process("routeCompleteProcessor")
            .log("Route processing is Completed : ${header.CamelFileNameOnly}")
            .end()
        .log("Starting the file process: ${header.CamelFileNameOnly}")
        .process("routeCBCheckProcessor")
        .unmarshal().gzipDeflater()
        .split(body().tokenizeXML("example", "*"),new SimpleStringAggregator()).streaming()
            .parallelProcessing(true)
            .process("lineProcessor")
        .end()
        .log("aggregate is completed :${header.CamelFileNameOnly}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you began to build an idempotent file consumer with an idempotent repository.

Have you tried to use the [built-in idempotent file consumer of Camel](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html#_avoiding_reading_the_same_file_more_than_once_idempotent_consumer) (with optional repository included)?

I think this should also work for SFTP since the component has the `idempotent` option and the SFTP component is an extension of the file component.